# Deriving Icon image location in MEL

Tags: icons, location, maya, mel

I am trying to figure out where a MEL code, particularly where it has
gotten its icon image from....

I was trying out a small test in Maya, in which as I change the format of the
image, whether is it is the form of .xpm to .png etc. I am unable to determine
if it is deriving from... I'm running on 2 servers and hence, I have got no idea if it is coming from server A or server B...

Is there any codes etc. that enables me to determine it? Or any other ways? I am using linux too

```
string $window = `window -title "shelfButton Example"`;
string $tabs = `tabLayout`;
string $shelf = `shelfLayout`;

shelfButton
    -enableCommandRepeat 1
    -enable 1
    -width 32
    -height 32
    -mw     0
    -mh     0
    -manage 1
    -visible 1
    -label "Render to Git"
    -image1 "rexSpotLight.xpm"
    -style "iconOnly";


tabLayout -edit -tabLabel $shelf "Example Shelf" $tabs;

showWindow $window;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all of the image search paths are in

```
getenv XBMLANGPATH;
```

in mel.  I believe the are used in the given order so the first path containing the bitmap is the one which you are seeing.  You'll need to split the paths (they're bunched by semicolons) and check each one to see where the actual file is.

**EDIT** note corrected spelling:  XBM, not XMB

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I just tried running the code you have provided... But I am not seeing any results display in the History otherwise than the given code itself... Am I doing it wrong?